# Delphi TList<T> Left side cannot be assigned to

Tags: delphi

I am getting a E2064 left side cannot be assigned to.

```
type
  LampRec = Record
    Intens : TVector3D;
    Loc : TVector3D;
    Rad : Real;
    RadSqr : Real;
  End;

var
  LampList : TList<LampRec>;
  ListLoop : integer;

begin
  for ListLoop := 1 to LampList.Capacity do
    with LampList.Items[ListLoop] do
      begin
        Intens.Zero();
        Loc.Zero();
        Rad := 0.0; //E2064 Left side cannot be assigned to
        RadSqr := 0.0; //E2064 Left side cannot be assigned to
      end;
end;
```

None of the members of LampRec are constant?

Comment: Websearch on the error message takes you to lots of duplicates. There's also the documentation https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2064_Left_side_cannot_be_assigned_to_(Delphi)

Comment: Thanks for your input David. I will add properties with get and set to the record. Cheers.

Comment: Adding setter will change that it compiles but it will not work - when using records in a `TList<T>` you cannot change them by accessing them via the default index property `Items`. That is because they are value types and the `Items` getter will return a copy. When you mutate their state you then only change that of the copy and not the one in the list. To directly access the records in the list you need to use the `List` property. See https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.List And then you can directly access the fields anyway.